# How to scrape 2 level web page from a website

Tags: python, sql, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I would like to ask you how to scrape web pages using python + Beautiful soup or Scrapy that contains for example job announcements if there are 2 level pages, a short description + a LINK to a full detail of the job post ? I need to scrape data from the title of the jobs announcements then go deeper and extract full description and add that data to a database or text file ? the problem is going to the second level where the full description lives and get the full detail, including image links if exists...
Anyone have done that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide the url you are looking after to scrap?

Answer (score 0):

check:

- https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links
- https://github.com/zseta/scrapy-templates/blob/master/website%20spider%20templates/1fol_pag2scr.py

if I understand what you want to do, I would save what you need... companyName, description, secondlinks, etc

then for each company saved, make a request to secondLinks and save/set information